# Does a dodecathorpe unicode character exist?

Tags: unicode

A hash/octothorpe character has two horizontal and two vertical lines. Is there a character with three and three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there a character with three and three?

Yes, it looks like ⩩

```
Name:                   Triple Horizontal Bar with Triple Vertical Stroke
Unicode Version:        3.2 (March 2002)
Block:                  Supplemental Mathematical Operators, U+2A00 - U+2AFF
Plane:                  Basic Multilingual Plane, U+0000 - U+FFFF
Script:                 Code for undetermined script (Zyyy)
Category:               Math Symbol (Sm) 
Bidirectional Class:    Other Neutral (ON)
Combining Class:        Not Reordered (0)
Character is Mirrored:  No
HTML Entity:            &#10857;
                        &#x2A69;
UTF-8 Encoding:         0xE2 0xA9 0xA9
UTF-16 Encoding:        0x2A69
UTF-32 Encoding:        0x00002A69
```

Source: [“⩩” U+2A69 Triple Horizontal Bar with Triple Vertical Stroke Unicode Character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2A69)